# Sorting content of the file in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, file, sorting

Hello guys I am really new to python and I am trying to sort the /etc/passwd file using PYTHON 3.4 based on the following criteria: 
Input (regular /etc/passwd file on linux system:

```
raj:x:501:512::/home/raj:/bin/ksh
ash:x:502:502::/home/ash:/bin/zsh
jadmin:x:503:503::/home/jadmin:/bin/sh
jwww:x:504:504::/htdocs/html:/sbin/nologin
wwwcorp:x:505:511::/htdocs/corp:/sbin/nologin
wwwint:x:506:507::/htdocs/intranet:/bin/bash
scpftp:x:507:507::/htdocs/ftpjail:/bin/bash
rsynftp:x:508:512::/htdocs/projets:/bin/bash
mirror:x:509:512::/htdocs:/bin/bash
jony:x:510:511::/home/jony:/bin/ksh
amyk:x:511:511::/home/amyk:/bin/ksh
```

Output that I am looking for either to the file or returned to the screen:

```
Group 511 : jony, amyk, wwwcorp
Group 512 : mirror, rsynftp, raj
Group 507 : wwwint, scpftp 
and so on
```

Here is my plan:

```
1) Open and read the whole file or do it line by line 
2) Loop through the file using python regex 
3) Write it into temp file or create a dictionary 
4) Print the dictionary keys and values
```

I will really appreciate the example how it can be done efficiently or apply any 
sorting algorithm. 
Thanks!

Comment: You don't need regex for this. Just split by ":" and take the name (0th element) and gid (3rd element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the file, throw it into a list and then throw all the users into some kinda hash table

```
with open("/etc/passwd") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

group_dict = {}
for line in lines:
    split_line = line.split(":")
    user = split_line[0]
    gid = split_line[3]
    # If the group id is not in the dict then put it in there with a list of users 
    # that are under that group
    if gid not in group_dict:
        group_dict[gid] = [user]
    # If the group id does exist then add the new user to the list of users in 
    # the group
    else:
        group_dict[gid].append(user)

# Iterate over the groups and users we found. Keys (group) will be the first item in the tuple, 
# and the list of users will be the second item. Print out the group and users as we go
for group, users in group_dict.iteritems():
    print("Group {}, users: {}".format(group, ",".join(users)))
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, any chance you can put the comments for the second part of the script for me to better understand the flow

Comment: I added some comments to the code. The python documentation is also very helpful if you are having trouble understanding some of the syntax as well

Answer (score 1):

This should loop through your `/etc/passwd` and sort users by group. You don't have to do anything fancy to solve this problem.

```
with open('/etc/passwd', 'r') as f:
    res = {}

    for line in f:
        parts = line.split(':')

        try:
            name, gid = parts[0], int(parts[3])
        except IndexError:
            print("Invalid line.")
            continue

        try:
            res[gid].append(name)
        except KeyError:
            res[gid] = [name]

for key, value in res.items():
    print(str(key) + ': ' + ', '.join(value))
```

Comment: Not bad, Andreas.  FWIW, we (mostly) prefer an indentation of 4 spaces around here. You have a superfluous `;` after `res = {}`, and to teach the Python beginners good habits you  _could_ use a slightly more meaningful name than `res`. And if you're going to test for `IndexError` perhaps you should print an error message rather than silently continuing. Also, why just test for `IndexError` and not for `ValueError: invalid literal for int()`? But kudos for using [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) on the `dict` insertion.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, any chance you can put the comments so I can better understand the code ?

Comment: @Zerg12: Maybe you should read the section in the official Python tutorial on `try: ... except`: [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html). That should help you to understand the bulk of Andreas' code.

Comment: Sorry, have been writing too much JavaScript lately. Will change the indentation to four spaces. :)